# command already defined error, but no package conflict

Tags: errors

I defined a new command in latex using the `\newcommand{}{}` directive:

```
\newcommand{\endlfolge}{\foo}
```

(abbreviation of the two german words *endliche Folge*)
and LaTeX gives me the following error:

```
! LaTeX Error: Command \endlfolge already defined.
```

I am really sure there is no conflict with other packages, since the error still occurs after renaming it:

```
\newcommand{\endlfolgeevbupbhliqvube}{\foo}

! LaTeX Error: Command \endlfolgeevbupbhliqvube already defined.
```

What is the problem?

Comment: note that you have have only shown part of the error message, missing out the part that is relevant here.  the message is `! LaTeX Error: Command \endlfolgeevbupbhliqvube already defined.
               Or name \end... illegal, see p.192 of the manual.`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Nice to know! My latex editor (Kile) only shows me what I've posted. So I think this Q&A is still useful.

Comment: editors are supposed to be helpful, truncating the error message isn't really that helpful (although I know some tex editors do it) if you look in the log file you should see the real message.

Answer (score 5):

I found out what's wrong: New commands cannot start with the letters `end`. Renaming

```
\newcommand{\endlfolge}{\foo}
```

to

```
\newcommand{\myendlfolge}{\foo}
```

solved the issue.

Comment: If you want to define a command starting with `\end` without diving into TeX, `\NewDocumentCommand` from the [`xparse`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/xparse) package and its siblings might be of help.